# Pass variable between callbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have an ActiveRecord model like the following, with the goal of sending a notification if the user has completed his (previously uncomplete) profile:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_update :check_profile
  after_update :notify_profile_completed

  def is_complete?
    # run some tests
  end

  private
  def check_profile
    @complete = is_complete?
  end

  def notify_profile_completed
    if is_complete? and not @complete
      # send notification
    end
  end
end
```

If I run an update, when the `@complete = is_complete?` code is reached, something goes wrong and the whole update fails without any error message.

I suppose that this is not the way to pass a variable between the callbacks... so how to do so?

Comment: My 2 cents: ActiveRecord callbacks should not be doing anything that is not directly related to persistence. (Including sending notifications). Some good points are stated [here](http://samuelmullen.com/2013/05/the-problem-with-rails-callbacks/)

Comment: This is a nice advice ... Implementing the notification logic the way you point out in this article may solve my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_update :check_profile
  after_update :notify_profile_completed

  def is_complete?
    # run some tests
  end

  private
  def check_profile
    self.complete = is_complete? # Assuming complete is a column in User class
  end

  def notify_profile_completed
    if is_complete? and !complete
      # send notification
    end
  end
end
```

as you will not get @complete set in one method to another

Comment: Well, the problem is that `complete` is not a column in the User class, as I don't want to store sure an ephemeral data. Is there no other way to pass data inside the instance?

Comment: The problem is, that its probably not the same instance when the first call is made and when the second one is made, otherwise, your original code would have worked just fine.